# Sort Months from January to December in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to sort the month starting from January to December, however here's my case:

[Result of my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5tUb.png)

**Here's my query for the above picture**

```
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'January' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 1
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'February' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 2
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'March' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 3
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'April' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 4
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'May' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 5
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'June' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 6
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'July' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 7
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'August' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 8
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'September' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 9
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'October' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 10
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'November' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 11
UNION
SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales, 'December' AS NameMonth
FROM  sales_tbl
WHERE MONTH(transactionDate) = 12
```

**I tried to include this in the query to solve my problem:**

`ORDER BY MONTH(NameMonth)`

But, I got an error [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39vNi.png)

Originally, *NameMonth* is not a column in the table.

***Everyone's answer is so much appreciated.***

Comment: order by MONTH(transactionDate) @Roevic instead of MONTH(NameMonth).

Comment: @KenWhite apologies, im still new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

```
select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , datepart(Month, transactionDate) , -1 ) ) AS Sales, sum(totalAmount) As NameMonth from Mas_Transaction
group by datepart(Month, transactionDate)
order by datepart(Month, transactionDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use the following method to show you the sales output in one line per month. After that, you can use the Case When command to get the name of the month and perform the sort based on the ID of month (MonthID or MONTH(transactionDate)). try follow:

```
select * from(
    SELECT  SUM(totalAmount) AS Sales , MONTH(transactionDate) AS MonthID
    FROM  sales_tbl
    GROUP BY MONTH(transactionDate)
) as tbl order by tbl.MonthID
```

Answer (score 0):

The Following Query uses CTE instead of using subqueries/unions and is sorted by month and Year for more accuracy.

Explanation:
QUERY is Grouping data with CTE and Getting MonthName using DATENAME inline function then doing a normal select query and sorting data

```
WITH QUERY AS(
SELECT SUM(totalAmount) Sales,
MONTH(transactionDate) SalesMonth,
YEAR(transactionDate) SalesYear,
DATENAME(MONTH,transactionDate) NameMonth
FROM sales_tbl
GROUP BY MONTH(transactionDate),YEAR(transactionDate),DATENAME(MONTH,transactionDate) 
)
SELECT Sales,NameMonth,SalesYear
FROM QUERY
ORDER BY SalesYear,SalesMonth
```

References:

[DATENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)